# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'slice' and 'int' on python

Tags: python, time, series

Hello I try to do timeseries analysis but i got this traceback, anyone can help me pls?

Python version : 3.6.7

Dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices

```
# ARIMA LİBRARY
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pandas import datetime

# fit model
model = ARIMA(ts, order=(1,0,1)) # (ARMA) = (1,0,1)
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)

# predict
start_index = datetime(2015, 1, 4)
end_index = datetime(2018, 3, 25)
forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)

# visualization
plt.figure(figsize=(22,10))
plt.plot(data.date,data.avprice,label = "original")
plt.plot(forecast,label = "predicted")
plt.title("Time Series Forecast")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Mean Temperature")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Traceback :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-17297527abe9> in <module>()
     10 start_index = datetime(2015, 1, 4)
     11 end_index = datetime(2018, 3, 25)
---> 12 forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
     13 
     14 # visualization

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'slice' and 'int'
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict): "end (int, str, or datetime) – Zero-indexed observation number at which to end forecasting, ie., the first forecast is start. Can also be a date string to parse or a datetime type. **However, if the dates index does not have a fixed frequency, end must be an integer index** if you want out of sample prediction." -- you never set a dates parameter in the call to `ARIMA`

Comment: thanks for reply can you give an example